# Extracting coefficients from a regression in R

Tags: r

I have conducted a basic linear regression in R which gives me the coefficients below:

```
model$coefficients
(Intercept) log(TraLea$Length..mm.cat.) 
  -7.487426                    2.967886
```

I have made a matrix with these values `coeff <- as.matrix(model$coefficients)` but would like to extract this values simply to give me:

```
a = exp(Intercept)
b = slope/log(TraLea$Length..mm.cat.)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the names()

```
data(mtcars)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)

names(summary(fit))

names(summary(fit))
 [1] "call"          "terms"         "residuals"     "coefficients"  "aliased"       "sigma"         "df"            "r.squared"    
 [9] "adj.r.squared" "fstatistic"    "cov.unscaled"
```

Then

Intercept:

```
summary(fit)$coefficients[1,1]
```

Slope:

```
summary(fit)$coefficients[2,1]
```

Comment: `coef(fit)` provides direct access to the coefficients. There is no need for `summary`.

Answer (score 2):

The package `broom` is nice for handling model results.  An example with the `mtcars` data set:

```
library(broom)
data(mtcars)
test <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
results <- tidy(test)

results

         term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value
1 (Intercept) 37.285126  1.877627 19.857575 8.241799e-19
2          wt -5.344472  0.559101 -9.559044 1.293959e-10
```

From there you can extract your desired values into new variables:

```
a <- results$estimate[1]
b <- results$estimate[2]
```